# How to get user online status in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph.

I tried

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

to get user online status (online / busy / offline...) like the one in Outlook.

[image]

However, it won't give me any field like `onlineStatus`.

Is there an API to get user online status?

Comment: any update on this? Any new solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using the [presence-Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) (GET /users/{id}/presence).

Answer (score 4):

This is not available through the Microsoft Graph today, but we welcome community feedback! Please upvote/comment on [this UserVoice post](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17714167-skype-lync-in-microsoft-graph-such-as-presence) so our team can see interest in this endpoint being added to the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: The link no longer works..I'd also like this to be added to Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Dan's answer the Skype informations in general are not available in the graph so at the time of writing.
You can leverage the [UCWA web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/gettingstarted?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396) to get that information.
I published a [sample](https://github.com/sharepoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/js-skype-status) for sharepoint framework implementations a couple of weeks ago that can help you understand how it works.