# Possibility of using specific Teams features in a custom web chat app

Tags: microsoft-teams

Our internal employees are all using Teams. I'm researching how feasible it would be to use certain features of Teams for a custom web chat app. The actual back and forth conversation would not take place in Teams...it would be something I would build, possibly using SignalR.

The custom web chat application should allow our customers the ability to:

1. See the Teams status of an employee (Online/Offline)
2. Click on the employee to enter a chat room. (This chat room would be something I would create, possibly using SignalR)

I was wondering if it is possible to do the following with Teams:

1. Get the Online/Offline status of a user in Teams and display that in a custom web app.
2. Send data to a specific Teams user from a web app. (For example: when a customer clicks on an employee in the custom web app to start a chat, send a link to the employee that would send them to the chat room.)

Are these two things possible using Teams?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is an unusual scenario, had to think a bit about that! In terms of (1) I'm not sure about anything for that it Teams (it might exist, but not something I'm aware of), but perhaps the Microsoft Graph has a capability for that. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039789/how-to-get-user-online-status-in-microsoft-graph).

Regarding item 2, do the customers have Teams? If so, you can deep link directly into a chat with the specific employee. If not, are you wanting the end user to use, say, a bot on the web app, but the employee to be using Teams? If so, who would they be "Chatting" to? Would it be ok for the chat to be with a custom bot inside Teams? If so, you should look more at the concept of "Pro-active chat" in Teams (to initiate the new/latest conversation from the bot to the user). The only drawback is if they are "chatting" to multiple people at once this wouldn't work, because each customer's interaction would come in to the same chat window in the Bot.

Comment: I looked into Microsoft Graph and I'm not able to determine if accessing user presence is available...it looks like no.

On item 2, our customers would *not* have Teams. The idea is that when a customer clicks to start a chat with a specific employee it would create a new chat room (possibly with SignalR) and would send the URL of the newly created chat room to the employee (who is using Teams).

Comment: oh, I see - so the employee wouldn't -have- the chat in Teams, just receive the notification, right? In that case, the answer I gave would work fine - you could have a bot in Teams that sends the employee a pro-active message, which includes a link to the web conversation.

With regards the web conversation itself, and while we're  on the topic of Bots, that's exactly what a web bot is for - rather leverage the Bot Framework than trying to roll your own SignalR implementation. It'll give you access to a ton of stuff you'd otherwise need to build yourself.

Comment: I understand your first part and it looks possible to have a bot send a Teams user a proactive message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging). However, I'm confused when you say "...rather leverage the Bot Framework than trying to roll your own SignalR implementation." I don't understand how a Bot Framework can replace a back and forth conversation between a customer and an employee. Do you have a link to something I could check out to give me some info?

Comment: So, before we look at -how-, I think there are a bunch of reasons -why- to do this - Bot Framework has a bunch of built in things you'd need to build yourself, like state management, dialogs, adaptive cards, transcript logging etc. As to -how-, there's no 100% built in capability for this, but it certainly exists as design pattern, as part of the concept of "human handoff". In that case, the bot at some point "escalates" to a human, and then becomes the intermediary handling the conversation between the two parties. You'd be doing the same, just right from the get-go [out of space, continue:]

Comment: See, for example, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 where it talks about "Even after an agent is engaged, the bot remains the behind-the-scenes facilitator of the conversation. The user and agent never communicate directly with each other; they just route messages through the bot."

Comment: also "After the agent connects to the bot, the bot begins to route messages between user and agent. Although it may appear to the user and the agent that they are chatting directly with each other, they are actually exchanging messages via the bot. The bot receives messages from the user and sends those messages to the agent, and in turn receives messages from the agent and sends those messages to the user."

Comment: So, with that in mind, here's a Node sample: https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff and a C# version: https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

hope that helps?

Comment: This might also be useful: https://tompaana.github.io/content/chatbots_as_middlemen.html